# $E$ is finite measurable set, if $f_n$ converges in measure to $f$ then $\dfrac{1}{f_n}$ converges in measure to $\dfrac{1}{f}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, measurable-functions

Let $E$ be a measurable set of finite measure, $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure on $E$, $f$ is finite and $\neq0$ almost everywhere. Prove that $\dfrac{1}{f_n}$ converges in measure to $\dfrac{1}{f}$.

Here is my attempt:

For every $r > 0$, for every $\varepsilon >0$,

$\Big\{x \in E : \Big\vert \dfrac{1}{f_n} - \dfrac{1}{f} \Big\vert \ge r \Big\}$
$=\Big\{x \in E : \Big\vert \dfrac{f_n-f}{f_nf}\Big\vert \ge r \Big\} $
$=\Big\{x \in E : |f_n-f|\Big\vert \dfrac{1}{f_nf} \Big\vert \ge r \Big\} $.

Since $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure, $\Big\{x \in E : |f_n-f| \ge r \Big\} < \varepsilon$.

But I don't see how to evaluate $\Big\vert \dfrac{1}{f_nf} \Big\vert$ as well as deal with problem.

Please give me some hints. Any help or advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a missing condition, like $f$ must be bounded away from zero? (Consider a sequence of constant functions, $f_n=\frac1n$, and $f=0$.)

Comment: This is not true, as suggested in the example of grand_chat.

Comment: This has been addressed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3685367/how-to-prove-that-if-f-n-rightarrow-f-in-measure-then-dfrac1f-n-righta

Comment: @grand_chat oh sorry, I miss this condition  f_n(x) and f(x) are both not equal to zero, for all x in E.

Comment: But with this condition, I can't manage to get the correct answer.

Comment: @Oliver Diaz I saw your answer on that post. But I don't study probability now, so does it have a different approach?

Comment: the same proof used in probability theory works for general convergence in measure. Everything boils down to the fact that a sequence $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure if and only if any subsequence of $f_n$ has a further subsequences that converges to $f$ a.s.

Comment: I have a question. What is a.s stand for?

Comment: @FactorY I have posted an answer to the other question.

Comment: @grand_chat oh i see thanks :D it's useful approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This general result is useful:

Lemma: Suppose $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ is a finite measure space. A sequence $S=\{f_n\}$ converges in measure to $f$ iff any subsequence $\{f_{n'}\}$ of $S$ has a further subsequence $\{f_{n''}\}$ that converges $\mu$-a.s. to $f$

Sketch of proof of sufficiency:
First check that $f_n$ converges in measure to $f$ iff $\int|f_n-f|\wedge1\,d\mu\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$. This is pretty standard. Now suppose $f_n$ satisfies the hypothesis bu that $f_n$ does not converge in measure to $f$. Then there is a subsequence $\{f_{n'}\}$such that $\mu(|f_{n'}-f|>\varepsilon\}\geq\delta$ for some $\delta>0$ and $\varepsilon>0$. But then there is a subsequence $\{f_{n''}\}$ of $\{f_{n'}\}$ that converges to $f$ $\mu$-a.s. which would imply that $f_{n''}$ converges in measure to $f$. This is a contradiction.

The details can be usually find in measure theoretic books of probability (Kallenberg, Billingsley) and in many Measure theory textbooks.

Comment: I can't guess what does a.s mean? I just think a stands for almost and s would be?

Comment: almost surely (in analysis is most common to say almost everywhere)